# Expand Amazon EC2 HVM root partition

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudformation

I created a VM with the Amazon AMI HVM. In the partition configuration I changed the default 8GB root partition to something bigger (10 in my example).

Once up, I'm trying to resize but it's not working as it was with Paravirtual.

```
[root@ip-10-xx-xx-xx ~]# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  10G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
xvdb    202:16   0  30G  0 disk /media/ephemeral0
[root@ip-10-xx-xx-xx ~]# resize2fs /dev/xvda1
resize2fs 1.42.3 (14-May-2012)
The filesystem is already 2096635 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Why is resize2fs not working with HVM ? I know how to expand the root partition, by either mounting the volume on a second instance, or snapshot it, but it is very manual.

Since I'm using Cloudformation, with Paravirtual, I just have to set the VolumeSize and resize it once booted. What are my option with HVM ?

Answer (score 0):

Since HVM is using GPT formated partition, use gparted / gdisk instead of fdisk.

This can't be automated, but you can create an AMI once resized and use it, not ideal though.